# Is there any application which interacts with the user?

Tags: software-recommendation, lubuntu, programming, automation, application-finder

I'm very comfortable while using Linux or Lubuntu although Windows seemed a little faster but it hangs at a certain point. So I would like to thank all the programmers of Linux I really liked it ..

I'm looking for an app which makes linux more interactive I think Windows has a simplified and an interactive interface to some extent ..

Is there a Linux app which e.g. gives me recommendations about what I should do and what I should not do? and do things which are important without even telling me that! as an automated advisor user or as if it were a living thing giving me advice?

Comment: I hope not. The last thing I want is a system that does "important" things without telling me.

Answer (score 4):

**1st  part of your question** - **recommendations about what you should and should not** :

Ubuntu has built-in Desktop Guide, which is a must-read for any newbie (and not also) user.

There are tons of tutorials, articles, books and videos which you can read and apply.

Every Ubuntu flavour has its own wiki site and documentations.

And nearly all application has some documentation whether built-in or online.

Read, use and learn.

**2nd part - software to do things which are important without even telling me that:**

It would be something useless. People use computers for different purposes and no software can know what you want. It is like *"I want a phone which makes phone-calls automatically to necessary people"*.

One of the best advantages of Linux systems is that you can manage and customize your system to more extent than other OS. That is the thing which makes Linux more powerful.

Time passes and you may become more and more proficient. All geeks were once newbies.

Comment: I was looking for Compiz